# performClick() not working because it's in a different thread

Tags: android, android-studio

So essentially I want to simulate a **button** click in my android app, using a timer.

When the timer goes off, I do find the button then try using `performClick()` which crashes and closes the app.

The log of course made the problem quite clear: "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views." Which makes total sense.  Duh!

But I assume that since it's all my app there is a way to properly do this?

Comment: Hi Sergio, Remember this basics in Android. Any task other than modifying UI element has to be performed in a background thread.

Comment: Can you post your code ?@Sergio

Answer (score 1):

You can use `runOnUiThread()` in a background Thread in order to update the UI Thread:

```
      try {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Run your functions here 
                }
            });
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Yes, and thank you.   That so worked.  I would like to know, but not sure how to search for it...for those familiar with Windows programming ANY app could send a message to a button (in this case) as long as it could find it.

Is there an equivalent type of programming for Android currently?

Thank you again for your answer

Comment: welcome :) glad that it helped. I'm sorry but i couldn't really understand ur second question. lol...

Comment: Hi....

In Windows programming, the SDK, allows to post a message to ANY item you can see.  Doesn't matter that it belongs to another application or thread.  Buttons, windows, slider controls, etc.  So if we're talking about just a button:

Basically, I can find the handle to the button and post a message to it. Such as the message it would receive had a user clicked it with a mouse.  

Trying to find out if there's something comparable in Android.

Thanks